# How to align the last "li" element at the end of div?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this layout[image: current output]

But the desired output is this

[image: Desired output]

I have tried a lot of things, but none of them have worked so far, including 
setting the parent position relative, and the setting the (last) child's position as absolute and setting it's bottom to 0, but that doesn't works either. The reason why that won't work would be clear after reading the page's layout.

*html*

```
<section class="header-content">
    <div class="row no-margin">
        <div class="col-md-3 Head1">
            <h5>
                <a href="Head1.html">
                    Head 1</a></h5>
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="Head1.html#detail1" class="top_header_links_white">Detail 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Head1.html#detail2" class="top_header_links_white">Detail 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Head1.html">
                        <img src="@Url.Content("~/images/bg_images/view_more.png")" alt="view all details" /></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 Head2">
            <h5>
                <a href="Head2.html">
                    Head 2</h5>
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="Head2.html#detail1" class="top_header_links_white">Detail 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Head2.html#detail2" class="top_header_links_white">Detail 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Head2.html#detail3" class="top_header_links_white">Detail 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Head2.html#detail4" class="top_header_links_white">Detail 4</a></li>
                   <li><a href="Head2.html">
                        <img src="@Url.Content("~/images/bg_images/view_more.png")" alt="view all details" /></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 Head3">
             <h5>
                <a href="Head3.html">
                    Head 3</h5>
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="Head3.html#detail1" class="top_header_links_white">Detail 1</a></li>
                   <li><a href="Head3.html">
                        <img src="@Url.Content("~/images/bg_images/view_more.png")" alt="view all details" /></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 Head4">
            <h5>
                <a href="Head4.html">
                    Head 4</h5>
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="Head4.html#detail1" class="top_header_links_white">Detail 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Head4.html#detail2" class="top_header_links_white">Detail 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Head4.html#detail3" class="top_header_links_white">Detail 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Head4.html#detail4" class="top_header_links_white">Detail 4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Head4.html#detail5" class="top_header_links_white">Detail 5</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Head4.html#detail6" class="top_header_links_white">Detail 6</a></li>
                   <li><a href="Head4.html">
                        <img src="@Url.Content("~/images/bg_images/view_more.png")" alt="view all details" /></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

*css*

```
.header-content
{
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: 2px;
    margin-bottom: 1%;
}
.header-content div div
{
    padding-bottom: 999px;
    margin-bottom: -999px;
}
.header-content ul
{
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
}
```

the second css is to fill in the total height of div as container, in case there were less items. Any help appreciated.

**Update**
Setting the bottom to 0 of last child, while setting it's position to absolute, and the container's position to relative doesn't works *because* of the second part of the css. I have included that to make the container occupy the full height in case of there are less elements. But when I do that, it sets the last li to very low, as bottom is 0, but the padding is 999. Please read *and* understand the css before answering.

Comment: with the provided css it's not as you showed http://jsfiddle.net/t0cuev5r/

Comment: @Abzoozy: It is because of the I also have bootstrap.

Comment: I already added bootstrap css and js in js fiddle under external resources http://jsfiddle.net/t0cuev5r/1/ 
anyways check zombyii solution

Answer (score 0):

```css
.header-content {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: 2px;
  margin-bottom: 1%;
}
.header-content ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}
.col-md-3 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 400px;
  float: left;
  border: 2px solid black;
  position: relative;
}
ul li:last-child img {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<section class="header-content">
  <div class="row no-margin">
    <div class="col-md-3 Head1">
      <h5>
                <a href="Head1.html">
                    Head 1</a></h5>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="Head1.html#detail1" class="top_header_links_white">Detail 1</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="Head1.html#detail2" class="top_header_links_white">Detail 2</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="Head1.html">
              <img src="@Url.Content(" ~/images/bg_images/view_more.png ")" alt="view all details" />
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 Head2">
      <h5>
                <a href="Head2.html">
                    Head 2</h5>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="Head2.html#detail1" class="top_header_links_white">Detail 1</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="Head2.html#detail2" class="top_header_links_white">Detail 2</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="Head2.html#detail3" class="top_header_links_white">Detail 3</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="Head2.html#detail4" class="top_header_links_white">Detail 4</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="Head2.html">
              <img src="@Url.Content(" ~/images/bg_images/view_more.png ")" alt="view all details" />
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 Head3">
      <h5>
                <a href="Head3.html">
                    Head 3</h5>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="Head3.html#detail1" class="top_header_links_white">Detail 1</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="Head3.html">
              <img src="@Url.Content(" ~/images/bg_images/view_more.png ")" alt="view all details" />
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 Head4">
      <h5>
                <a href="Head4.html">
                    Head 4</h5>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="Head4.html#detail1" class="top_header_links_white">Detail 1</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="Head4.html#detail2" class="top_header_links_white">Detail 2</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="Head4.html#detail3" class="top_header_links_white">Detail 3</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="Head4.html#detail4" class="top_header_links_white">Detail 4</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="Head4.html#detail5" class="top_header_links_white">Detail 5</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="Head4.html#detail6" class="top_header_links_white">Detail 6</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="Head4.html">
              <img src="@Url.Content(" ~/images/bg_images/view_more.png ")" alt="view all details" />
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score -1):

Add this to your CSS

```
.header-content ul { position: relative; height: 100%; }
.header-content ul li:last-child { position: absolute; bottom: 0; }
```

Comment: Did you read my question completely? I explicitly said it didn't worked.

Comment: I missed that part, let me try again.

Comment: I've also added the explanation as to why it didn't (and won't) work.

Comment: I'm not sure of the rest of the styles that you used, but in this fiddle, it works: http://jsfiddle.net/cxx9pqnj/, other than CSS in my answer, I added `.header-content ul { height: 100%; }`